# Bitwise "and" operation into the kotlin

Tags: kotlin, bitwise-operators

If negative number is from -31 to -1 then I would like represent it into the format 111XXXXX.
I try to do it using "and" bitwise operator:

```
println("0b00011111 & 0xe0 is ${0b00011111 and 0xe0}")
println("31 & 0xe0 is ${31 and 0xe0}")
println("0b00011111 & 0b11100000 is ${0b00011111 and 0b11100000}")
```

But the result is always 0. Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: You mention your actual results (0) but what are you expected results?

Comment: I expect that the result will be 0b11111111 or 255.

Comment: Oh! I understand. I use wrong operator. The question could be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It prints 0 because `00011111 and 11100000` always returns `0`. The return type of `and` is `Int`, so if you want to print it in base 2 with leading zeroes, you have to format it.

To convert it to a `String` in base 2, you can call the `toString` method on `Int` with a radix parameter:

```
val numberString = (0b00011111 and 0b11100000).toString(2);
```

This will give you the number in binary format, but without leading zeroes. You need to left-pad with zeroes to get the format you want. I leave that task up to you (hint: `padStart`) ;)

Comment: Print is just example. I would like to print Int number. Why {0b00011111 and 0b11100000} always returns 0? 0b00011111  is Int number . 0b11100000 is Int number. And returns Int.

Comment: It is always 0, because that is what it is mathematically. What do you mean?

Comment: A better way (imo) to convert to string would be `(0b00011111 and 0x11100000).toString(2)`. That way you don't have to use Java classes

Comment: @therealfarfetchd Oh, nice :) That function was introduced in Kotlin 1.1. This answer was written before that.